# Keeps getting cannot Error: Cannot find module from @hookforms/resolver

Tags: npm, next.js, react-hook-form, yup

I am working on a next js project and while refreshing the page i am getting this error. But when i start from beginning that is signing in and then visiting other pages then this error wont appear. But if there is any error in fetching data from api then it appears.

Here's the complete log:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\abhit\Desktop\Minimal_JavaScript_v3.0.0\Minimal_JavaScript_v3.0.0\modified\node_modules\@hookform\resolvers\yup\dist\yup'
at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:15)
at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:953:15)
at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:483:14)
at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:523:31)
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:27)
at mod._resolveFilename (file://C:\Users\abhit\Desktop\Minimal_JavaScript_v3.0.0\Minimal_JavaScript_v3.0.0\modified\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\require-hook.js:27:32)
at mod._resolveFilename (file://C:\Users\abhit\Desktop\Minimal_JavaScript_v3.0.0\Minimal_JavaScript_v3.0.0\modified\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\require-hook.js:27:32)
at mod._resolveFilename (file://C:\Users\abhit\Desktop\Minimal_JavaScript_v3.0.0\Minimal_JavaScript_v3.0.0\modified\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\require-hook.js:27:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
getServerError @ client.js?4d30:7
eval @ index.js?46cb:709
setTimeout (async)
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
 "name": "apsit-community",
 "author": "apsit",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Platform build by students for the students.",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "lint": "next lint",
   "lint:es": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx .",
   "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx .",
   "dev": "next dev -p 3031",
   "build": "next build",
   "start": "next start"
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.19.3",
   "@emotion/cache": "^11.7.1",
   "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
   "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
   "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
   "@fullcalendar/common": "^5.10.1",
   "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
   "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
   "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.10.1",
   "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.10.1",
   "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
   "@fullcalendar/timeline": "^5.10.1",
   "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.7",
   "@iconify/react": "^3.1.0",
   "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.60",
   "@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
   "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.2.1",
   "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.21",
   "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.1",
   "@turf/bbox": "^6.5.0",
   "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.3",
   "apexcharts": "^3.32.0",
   "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.2.0",
   "axios": "^0.24.0",
   "change-case": "^4.1.2",
   "cookie": "^0.4.1",
   "d3-array": "^3.1.1",
   "d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
   "date-fns": "^2.27.0",
   "deck.gl": "^8.6.5",
   "emoji-mart": "^3.0.0",
   "firebase": "^9.6.1",
   "framer-motion": "^5.5.5",
   "geojson": "^0.5.0",
   "highlight.js": "^11.3.1",
   "i18next": "^21.6.3",
   "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
   "immutable": "^4.0.0",
   "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
   "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
   "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
   "lodash": "^4.17.19",
   "mapbox-gl": "^2.6.1",
   "next": "^12.0.7",
   "next-transpile-modules": "^9.0.0",
   "notistack": "^2.0.3",
   "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
   "numeral": "^2.0.6",
   "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
   "react": "^17.0.1",
   "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
   "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
   "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.4",
   "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
   "react-dropzone": "^11.4.2",
   "react-hook-form": "^7.22.2",
   "react-i18next": "^11.15.1",
   "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.4",
   "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
   "react-map-gl": "^6.1.18",
   "react-markdown": "^7.1.1",
   "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
   "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
   "react-slick": "^0.28.0",
   "redux": "^4.1.2",
   "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
   "rehype-raw": "^6.1.0",
   "simplebar": "^5.3.6",
   "simplebar-react": "^2.3.6",
   "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
   "stylis": "^4.0.13",
   "stylis-plugin-rtl": "^2.1.1",
   "worker-loader": "^3.0.8",
   "yup": "^0.32.11"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.0.7",
   "eslint": "^7.32.0",
   "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.7",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
   "prettier": "2.5.1",
   "typescript": "^4.4.4"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because, you don't have "react-hook-form" So, Try the following:

```
npm install react-hook-form @hookform/resolvers yup
```